# What is the correct WINAPI_FAMILY for HoloLens

Tags: winapi, uwp, hololens

What is the correct `WINAPI_FAMILY` for **HoloLens**? There are a lot of `WINAPI_FAMILY` values and I want to be in a correct way while developing for HoloLens.

Answer (score 1):

HoloLens apps are UWP apps and there's nothing specific to HL here,  so that you can use the same WINAPI_FAMILY value as in any UWP app. For example, [MixedReality-WebRTC](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/tree/f8024421fae7f9892c4f2f7e7f0816bbcc0c5802) using this code for compilation compiltion in [line 33](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/libs/mrwebrtc/src/peer_connection.cpp#L33):

```
(WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_APP)
```

Besides, this repository also provided the best way to check if the app is running on HoloLens [in line 53](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/libs/mrwebrtc/src/peer_connection.cpp#L53).